# What's the most practical way to display multiple lines of text from an array on a view?

Tags: ios, uitableview

So I have an array populated with string and I want to print it out on the view (like what you often see in the command prompt/terminal). What's the best way to do it?

I have thought of some different ways but not absolutely sure about it

1. Use `UITableView` and input each string into a cell.
2. Use `UITextView` (I still haven't found out how to do it)

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text view is a tad easier (but both are incredibly simple). A table view opens the door for additional functionality (the ability to associate a tap on a cell with some action specific to that row of the array), as well affords you some more memory efficient approaches (important if dealing with an extremely large data set), etc. But if you have a modest array of strings and want it to look like what you see at command line window, the text view can probably achieve that with the minimum amount of effort.

Other approaches (e.g. scroll view with `UILabel` controls that you add programmatically, etc.) are even more cumbersome, so I think the two options you've identified are the best candidates.

Comment: Thanks for telling me what's the best idea is :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can create a string in one line directly from the array using:

```
NSString *displayString = [<yourArray> componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

Then set the display string into a view in you UI.

Answer (score 2):

`yourTextView.text = [yourArray description];`

or

`yourTextView.text = [[yourArray valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];`

will dump it into a textView without making it look fancy (just like a command prompt).

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your array creating a string, then set that as the `text` property of a `UITextView`. Something like:

```
NSMutableString *finalText = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for(NSString *line in array)
{
    [finalText appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", line]];
}

textView.text = finalText;
```

---

Another option would be to use:

```
textView.text = [array componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

This is probably a better option for you since you won't be left with a trailing newline at the end.

Comment: Oh yes, why do I forget the appendString >"<. If I add some new strings in my array, that method will help me a lot. Thanks for helping me out :D